# How can I achieve this Positioning with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

Situation:

```
 _______________________________________
|             .ParentContainer          |
|    _______      ____________          |
|   |       |    |            |         |
|   |.Block1|    |.Block2     |         |
|   |       |    |            |         |
|   |       |    |            |         |
|   |_______|    |            |         |
|                |            |         |
|                |            |         |
|                |            |         |
|                |            |         |
|                |____________|         |
|_______________________________________|
```

I need to add `Block3` dynamically after `Block2`. To be more precise, in the DOM it needs to come after `Block2` but on the page it must appear underneath Block1.

So I'd like to see something like this:

```
 _______________________________________
|             .ParentContainer          |
|    _______      ____________          |
|   |       |    |            |         |
|   |.Block1|    |.Block2     |         |
|   |       |    |            |         |
|   |       |    |            |         |
|   |_______|    |            |         |
|                |            |         |
|    _______     |            |         |
|   |       |    |            |         |
|   |.Block3|    |            |         |
|   |       |    |            |         |
|   |       |    |____________|         |
|   |_______|                           |
|                                       |
|_______________________________________|
```

The code is simple:

```
<div class="ParentContainer clearfix">
    <div class="Block1 leftFloat></div>
    <div class="Block2 leftFloat></div>
</div>
```

I've got jQuery which will append the next block (`Block3`) after block2 but I'm unsure how to achieve the result above with this markup...

Comment: Is it an option to absolutely position Block2? Or float it right?

Comment: Can't position it absolutely. It's the last block on the line (meaning nothing comes after it horizontally) so I think it may be possible to float it right?

Comment: Okay then, try the right float, and no float on the other blocks. You might need to tweak widths/max-widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this idea, and use jQuery's [**.after():**](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
.ParentContainer div {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
div.Block2 {
    float:right;
    clear: none;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dSwJB/)

Comment: This is what I had too, but the problem is when the width drops below 33%. Then he needs to use a negative top margin if he knows the height of the block 1 (which can be done with JS/jQ).

Comment: @Shomz, can you refactor the fiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: This did exactly as needed too. @Shomz with the width, do you mean the width of the parent container? Or block3?

Comment: Sure @Sergio: http://jsfiddle.net/qLgJC/1/
I meant the width of each block (child divs), see my answer.

Comment: That's it! Much neater.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you'll want to have Block1, Block3, Block2, and have 1 and 3 floated left. To add in the third block dynamically, use insertBefore. insertBefore is just like appendChild, but it allows you to put it before the last element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.insertBefore

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the float from the blocks 1 and 3, and right float the block 2.

However, if you use the right float, you'd need to use a negative top margin for the block 2 to compensate for the height of block 1 (sounds complicated but it isn't). See here: http://jsfiddle.net/75SBx/3/

```
$('.b2').css('margin-top', '-' + $('.b1').css('height')); // can include margins, borders...
```